# Anyone know what this 4 inch pipe on the outside of my house could be?

Tags: plumbing

Does anyone know what this 4 inch pipe on the outside of my house could be for? It has a concrete base around it. We are installing an egress window that is next to this and wondering if this pipe is functional for something else.

[image: Pipe outside of house]

Comment: Have someone flush a toilet while you listen for noise. It may be a vent that someone cut off or a clean out without a cap.

Comment: Have you usef a fish tape or other means to see how deep it goes?  Are you in a community where some people use well water?  Does it look like someone did a cut at the top of the pipe?

Comment: Good idea about listening for noise. I'll give that a try. I have not put anything down it yet to see the depth. I do have on of those endoscope cameras I may try to drop down later. I was thinking maybe it was cut off, but one edge of the pipe you can see is a little bent and I am not sure if that would be a result of cutting it or not. This end of the house has no plumbing fixtures nearby, at least now, which makes me wonder what it could be for. The main drain line to the house is on the opposite site of the house. I have 3 stack vents through the roof too.

Comment: If this is over 10' deep, it would have been used for a hand pump well system.  Water to use for watering plants etc. outside the house.  Not necessary for portable water.

Comment: Any chance it's for a flag pole or a pole for a sail awning?

Comment: There's a very good chance it was for a pole or something else. I am not familiar with what a sail awning is, but my concrete patio which is about 6 feet from this pipe has several sets of drilled holes where I have wondered what used to be installed over it...

Comment: @Logan A sail awning is a large piece of material cut in different shapes with ropes at the corners. the ropes can be attached to poles or to buildings and pulled tight. A shady portable roof...

Comment: The "bent over part" looks like damage/wear common for a post base in the direction the post is laid down or stood up from.

Comment: Turns out it was just about 3ft deep. When we dug it up, it was encased in a large 3ft x 3ft block of concrete. Very odd, but seemed to be a pole of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

Quite possibly it was a pole for a clothes drying line that was cut off once no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

It could be for radon.

Half your state has a lot of radon and the other half has more than normal.

I’d verify before installing an operable window that could allow gas back into the house. In fact, just to be safe, I’d move the window.

Comment: Yeah, it definitely wasn't a radon mitigation system, I am familiar with those too. There was an existing window there and we were replacing it.

Comment: Usually radon pipes are extended up to a dry location so the airway remains open...but just an idea.